# Count the number of dictionaries from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, count

I have a dictionary that contains a list of dictionaries. I want to count the number dictionaries within the list. My data looks like this:

```
{
"Ratings": [
    {
        "User": "User1",
        "Rating": 2
    },
    {
        "User": "User2",
        "Rating": 4
    }
}
```

I tried the following which worked but wanted to know if there is a better way.

```
print(sum(map(len, dict_1.values())))
```

Comment: If this is your exact structure, you can simply do `len(dict_1['Ratings'])`. But you're using `sum`, so I'm not sure if the original dictionary has many such lists and you're combining their lengths?

Comment: @shriakhilc That's much simpler, the structure is exactly as shown, I guess your suggestion is the best.  Do you know how should I proceed to calculate the mean of all the rating?

Comment: `sum(r['Rating'] for r in dict_1['Ratings'])/len(dict_1['Ratings'])` should do the trick for a simple mean

Comment: @shriakhilc Thanks man, really helpful!